# regime switching multivariate garch

Tags: python, r, markov-models

I have a regression with 4 independent variables and a dependent variable. I want to implement a Regime switching GARCH model but have been unable to find a package in R,Python or Matlab. MSGARCH package available in R is for uni-variate series series, apart from this I haven't come across any available packages. 
Is there any available package?

Comment: Please add your current code as an example.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, there is available the [MS_Regress-Matlab](https://github.com/msperlin/MS_Regress-Matlab), which can be connected to the

MFE toolbox of Sheppard for more functionalities.

Let me know if this helps, or if you have found any other way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a MATLAB code developed recently to handle the multivariate MS GARCH model, check this [link](https://codeocean.com/capsule/9016375/tree/v1)